# Most Efficient Way to Related Data Entries

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, optimization, google-cloud-datastore

I am building a website using Google App Engine in Python but this question should apply to anything similar not just this specific framework.  I am trying to decide between two models of relating data.

They involve a Location database class and each Location entity has multiple Experience database entities hooked to it.

Right now I have the Locations classes in their own memcache and I have reference to each Experience stored in a expRef IntegerProperty.  I then do Experience.get_by_id(expRef) to get all of the Experiences and display them on the Location page.

```
class Location(ndb.Model):
    #a bunch of other properties
    expRefs = ndb.IntegerProperty(repeated=True)
class Experience(ndb.Model):
            #a bunch of other properties with no ref to Location

#here is the handler for the Location page
location = individual_location_cache(keyid)
exps= []
            if location.expRefs != []:
                for ref in location.expRefs:
                    records.append(Record.get_by_id(ref))
```

I am wondering if this is the best option or if it would be better to give each Experience a reference to the Location property and then store all of the references in Memcached and make two calls to memcached, one for the Location and then one for all of the experiences there.

```
class Location(ndb.Model):
        #a bunch of other properties but no ref to experiences
class Experience(ndb.Model):
        #a bunch of other properties
        locationRef = ndb.IntegerProperty()

#the Location page handler starts here
location = individual_location_cache(keyid)
exps= exp_location_cache(keyid)
```

Is there a big difference or any options I am forgetting?

Comment: It's always easier to define your problem with code than with natural language, can you provide some code of what you've written, and what you're thinking about doing?

Comment: alright I think that should help a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The the way you're storing it looks okay - one very obvious thing you'd want to optimize though, is to fetch experiences as a batch:

```
exps= []
        if location.expRefs != []:
            for future in [Record.get_by_id_async(ref) for ref in location.expRefs]:
                records.append(future.get_result())
```

This way NDB will try to fetch all your experiences via one query - and will automatically cache them in memcache.